# markdown tag content not properly showing in angular

Tags: angular, r-markdown, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am using NGX-markdown NPM for show content in markdown tag.

```
<markdown [data]='markdown' ></markdown>
```

I install required NPM and import like below.

```
import 'prismsjs';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-typescript.min.js';
import 'prismjs/plugins/line-numbers/prism-line-numbers.js';
import 'prismjs/plugins/line-highlight/prism-line-highlight.js';
```

angular.json --

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "node_modules/@costlydeveloper/ngx-awesome-popup/styles/theme.css",
              "node_modules/prismjs/plugins/line-numbers/prism-line-numbers.css",
              "node_modules/prismjs/themes/prism-okaidia.css"
            ],
```

I get reference from this. [stackbizz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-markdown?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

In this page showing correct content like below.

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2uP5.png)

When I use same code then its showing this type.

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl4Qn.png)

In My case list of number is not showing how we can fix this.

I am using Same code like I provided stack Bizz reference code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue here is with css. Is it possible that your styles is overriding the styles that you expect to see?
Did you try to remove all of the .css imports except for the prism once?
And what do you see in chrome dev tools when you check on the elements of the list?

Basically you need to see if you have a

```
li {
    list-style: none;
  }
```

In any of your .css files and override it in styles.css or remove the file that causes the issue.

[image]

Comment: I am trying remove all .css property except for the prism but its showing same problem.
In my case only numbering is not showing (ordered list and unordered list numbering) in markdown tag. I have also added image please see both image to understand my problem.

Comment: Yes, I see. The lists are not showing. Can you provide a stackbizz of your code? I cannot reproduce your issue, so it's hard to help. 

Also, you can try looking at the css code of the lists 
[using devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/reference#:~:text=In%20your%20viewport%2C%20right%2Dclick,element%20in%20the%20DOM%20Tree.)
And see if you have a style like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style) on your list elements.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-markdown?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I am using same code like this

Comment: I saw the example code you used, but apparently something is different in your code, if you see different results. Please, provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so I would be able to help.